# Staggered Grid Layout behavior issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout, staggeredgridlayout, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

I`m new in Android.
Could somebody help with "strange" StaggeredGridLayout behavior. GIFs attached below:

[first_example_StaggeredGridLayout_behavior.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCtv8.gif)

[second_example_StaggeredGridLayout_behavior.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgM2x.gif)

My recycler init code:

```
 val layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(resources.getInteger(R.integer.span_value), StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
 layoutManager.gapStrategy = StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS
 photoRecycler.adapter = adapterUnsplash
 photoRecycler.layoutManager = layoutManager
 photoRecycler.addItemDecoration(StaggeredItemDecoration(view.resources.getInteger(R.integer.column_spacing)))
```

ItemDecoration class

```
class StaggeredItemDecoration constructor(private var space: Int)
: RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State?) {
       val halfSpacing = space / 2
       outRect.set(halfSpacing, halfSpacing, halfSpacing, halfSpacing)

 }
}
```

I've researched a lot of sources, but all didn`t help with my issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what behavior? ?

Comment: What is strange in this ? Can you elaborate

Comment: same issue I am facing

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using item Animator?

```
photoRecycler.setItemAnimator(null);
```

The above piece of code will remove the default animator applied to the recycler view.